# Using jquery.effects.slide, how to combine direction, speed, and completed function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide

I found jquery.effects.slide works according to what I need. But I am having trouble figuring out how to combine all possible arguments with a completed function.

For example, this basically does what I want, slide a div from left to right:

```
$("#companyinfo").show('slide', function(){
    //do stuff here as a condition of the completed slide effect.
});
```

But when I introduce a speed of 500, it doesn't seem to recognize the additional argument:

```
$("#companyinfo").show('slide', 500, function(){});
```

And what if I want to change the direction?

```
$("#companyinfo").show('right', 'slide', 500, function(){});
```

The additional argument "right" breaks the slide effect.

So, I need to use `show` with: direction, speed, and completed function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#companyinfo").show("slide", {direction: 'right'}, 500, function() {
    //callbacks
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Vanilla jQuery doesn't have slide effects, but [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) does.

Comment: Look at my question again, please. I already explained I am using jquery.effects.slide, and it has slide effects.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?